# jquery load function not working in combination with other js code

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a problem regarding the combination of two parts of the code. This code alone is working fine:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="jquery.panelslider.min.js"></script>

 <script>
     $('#left-panel-link').panelslider();
     $('#close-panel-bt').click(function() {
         $.panelslider.close();
     });
```

But when I add this one below, the second function (panelslider.close) is not working anymore. Moreover, the load function of the second part of the code is not working neither.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#content').load('content/index.php');
    $('ul#menuslider li a').click(function() {
        var page = $(this).attr('href');
        $('#content').load('content/' + page + '.php');
        });
    });
```

I probably missed something important? Any help is welcome, as I don't know which keyword to use in order to look for a solution. I already tried "combine ajax and jquery", "load not working" and others, but without success.

Thanks in advance! Jonas

Comment: Define "not working"? Error messages? Unexpected output?

Comment: I think you need to use  [**Event Delegation**](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/). You should use [**.on()**](http://api.jquery.com/on/) using delegated-events approach. try, General Syntax `$(document).on(event, selector, eventHandler);`

Comment: use `noConflict()` https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

Comment: Thanks for the responses. But not working, I mean that the intended function is not working: no loading of php, no closing of panel. I tried the Delegation and noConflict without success. Maybe the problem is elswhere?

Comment: could you please make a small fiddle, or show us the markups?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
<script>
(function($){

    $('#left-panel-link').panelslider();
    var content = $('#content');
    content.load('content/index.php');

    $(document)
    .on('click', '#close-panel-bt', function() {
         console.log("about to close the panel");
         $.panelslider.close();
    })
    .on('click', 'ul#menuslider li a', function() {
        var page = $(this).attr('href');
        console.log("about to reload content");
        content.load('content/' + page + '.php');
    });

}(jQuery));
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks LShetty for providing this solution. Unfortunately not working either: no loading of content/index.php, no opening of the panel...

Comment: Looks like you have problems in the surrounding areas :) Check your browser console for JS erros.

Comment: I checked, changed "(jquery)" to "(jQuery)". No more errors detected by the console. The index.php is loading, but still no closing nore loading of other php. Hum, there are surely other problems I don't see...

Comment: Sorry about jquery, corrected. Do you see those 2 logs when you click?